# in java, is non-initialized object guarantee to be null?

Tags: java, jvm

public class T146 { //LRU Cache

```
private HashMap<Integer, DoubleLinkedListNode> map 
    = new HashMap<Integer, DoubleLinkedListNode>();
private DoubleLinkedListNode head;
private DoubleLinkedListNode end;
private int capacity;
private int len;

public LRUCache(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
    len = 0;
}
```

}

For this data structure.
if I initilized a instance of `T146`. 
Without setting `t146.head = null.` 
can jvm guarantee `t146.head` is `null`?
THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in java, is non-initialized object guarantee to be null?

Any non-initialized *reference variable* is guaranteed to be null *if it's a class or instance member.* Local variables have no default values at all, but the compiler will tell you if you try to use one before it's been initialized.